# Maven, how to copy files?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I want to copy some files (jar, launch scripts, docs) to some directory, like `dist/` in project root.

I am using **maven-assembly-plugin** and set `<configuration><outputDirectory>` in pom.xml. It creates files in `dist/` but inside `<my_project>-<decsriptor_id>/` subdirectory.

Is there any way to output it just in the root of `dist/`?

Or is there a plugin in Maven that simply copies files?

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>maven-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/dist</outputDirectory>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/maven-assembly/dist.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

dist.xml

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
    <id>dist</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>path........</source>
            <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
            <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
        </file>
    </files>
</assembly>
```

Comment: You told the plugin to create a directory with `<format>dir</format>`, so why are you surprised to have it in the output? Make a ZIP and see that there are no base directory here (because `<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>`), just the result of the format. What exactly is the task you're trying to accomplish? And files should _never_ be created in a place other than `target` (so `<outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/dist</outputDirectory>` is not a good idea).

Comment: just for convenience, to have all needed files (from different places) in one directory, and without all other stuff from target. Why is it not a good idea?

Comment: Simply because your src folder is under version control which means you are polluting it with generated files during your build...By default the target folder should be excluded so the target folder is the default for containing generated stuff (like compiled classes, compiles tests etc. and for created zip file or jar files)....This is the reason why it is not a good idea...

Comment: @khmarbaise um... Can't I just add `/dist/` to `.gitignore`?:) The same as `target`.

Comment: Of course you could but this is against the conventions in Maven to generate everything in `target` folder...

Answer (score 9):

You may use [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html):

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
    <id>copy-resources</id>
    <!-- insert here the phase you need -->
    <phase>validate</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>copy-resources</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/extra-resources</outputDirectory>
      <resources>        
        <resource>
        <directory>src/non-packaged-resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
      </resources>          
    </configuration>        
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```