# Maven copy the source files to a folder

Tags: maven

Is it possible to copy the source files from maven project to a folder before final compilation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven, how to copy files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654314/maven-how-to-copy-files)

Comment: First why do you need that? And what kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to copy the files to another directory.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <tasks>
            <copy todir="dest">
                <fileset dir="src">
                    <include name="**/*"/>
                </fileset>
            </copy>
        </tasks>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Generally this is used during the `install` or `deploy` build phases, but you can set the phase to be earlier in the Maven lifecycle if you require the files for another step in the build. You just need to change it in the execution. Take a look at [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Comment: This is a build smell...cause in the deploy phase only generated artifacts will be deployed to a remote repository....it does not make sense to copy files into another directory...this should be done earlier in package/prepare-package and using things like maven-assembly-plugin to create dist like package...