# How can I use multiple Maven local repositories with precedence

Tags: maven, maven-3

I would like to know if there any workaround about having multiple local repositories used by order.

Example :

Default local repository : `~/.m2/repository`

Work repository : `/var/tmp/m2LocalRepo`

When running Maven, to resolve dependencies I would like that at first it looks for the artifact in `/var/tmp/m2LocalRepo` if it does not find it it looks in the default one.

There is the issue [MNG-3655 – Allow multiple local repositories](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3655) which talks about the same problem but has not been resolved yet.

**UPDATE**

My use case is as follows:

- An application is represented by 2 maven projects `projectA` and `projectB` which have the same version.
- `projectB` is a dependency of `projectA`
- when developing a new feature, we create a development branch on each project with the same name. However, we do not modify the version number which remains the same as the main branch.
- During a build, on Jenkins for example, I would like to build `projectB` first but install its artifacts in another local repository (for example, `/var/tmp/m2LocalRepo`) and not on the default repository so as not to disrupt other builds that also depend on `projectB`. Then, during the build of `projectA`, I would like it to get the `projectB` dependency from `/var/tmp/m2LocalRepo` and the other dependencies from the local repository.

Comment: No. What is the use case? Maybe we can find a better solution for your use case.

Comment: @J Fabian Meier, see update :)

Comment: I don' think Maven supports that, and actually, it could be quite confusing if the same version means different things depending on context. If you need to build feature branches, I would change the version to something like `1.2.3-feature-SNAPSHOT`. If you don't want to change it in the POM, you could also use CI friendly versions (`${revision}`) and let Jenkins replace them.

Comment: The easiest solution is to use different versions as J Fabian Meier already suggested and don't install artifacts on a CI solution use a repository manager for such things and you can use the appropriate version on the other project ...best is to use the branch name (which usually follows a ticket system) ... Apart from that it sounds very likely as those projects belong together within a multi module build.... that would save duplicate branches hassle with your CI / deployment and dependencies and you can refactor within a single project with your IDE etc...

Answer (score 0):

Re "*During a build, on Jenkins for example*":

Jenkins Maven projects have an option **Build** → <kbd>Advanced...</kbd> → ☑ *Use private Maven repository* with its inline help:

> Normally, Jenkins uses the local Maven repository as determined by Maven — the exact process seems to be undocumented, but it's `~/.m2/repository` and can be overridden by  in `~/.m2/settings.xml` (see [the reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) for more details.)
>
> This normally means that all the jobs that are executed on the same node shares a single Maven repository. The upside of this is that you can save the disk space, but the downside of this is that sometimes those builds could interfere with each other. For example, you might end up having builds incorrectly succeed, just because your have all the dependencies in your local repository, despite that fact that none of the repositories in POM might have them.
>
> There are also some reported problems regarding having concurrent Maven processes trying to use the same local repository.
>
> When this option is checked, Jenkins will tell Maven to use `$WORKSPACE/.repository` as the local Maven repository. This means each job will get its own isolated Maven repository just for itself. It fixes the above problems, at the expense of additional disk space consumption.
>
> When using this option, consider setting up a Maven artifact manager so that you don't have to hit remote Maven repositories too often.
>
> If you'd prefer to activate this mode in all the Maven jobs executed on Jenkins, refer to the technique described [here](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Hudson-on-2-4-8-16-core-boxes-td371215.html#a371217).

and the options:

- Default ...
- Local to the executor
- Local to the workspace

You can copy `projectB`'s artifacts using the Maven Resources Plugin (as described in this [answer to *Maven, how to copy files?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41661030/1744774)) to `projectA`'s local repo on demand.